# Really Simple Open Source Java games

Tags: java, open-source

I need a simple open source Java game to assign it as a programming task to my friend who is learning Java and to be as a reference for him while re-implementing it. He wants to get his hands dirty with a real project but he is still in his first steps in learning the language so don't expect him to make a big game :)

EDIT: the game doesn't matter to be a console based game or a gui game. All what I need is giving him a good programming practice.

Comment: For basic Java concepts you might have him develop a vending machine and then extend the basic vending machine to different types such as pop, candy, dvd rental, etc. This can be done as a console app. Then when the basics are understood GUI can be added.

Comment: http://javalang.org/blog/2014/open-source-java-games

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) or [Greenfoot](http://www.greenfoot.org/door).

I think Greenfoot is better and nicer for learning Java. Learning should be fun otherwise your friend has to fight with simple things (ide, building problems, etc.) which are killing the fun.

Answer (score 2):

how about tic tac toe. Thats what we learned in VB class way back in the day, it has drawing needs, logic needs and is simple and universally understandable how to play.

http://www.javadb.com/the-tic-tac-toe-game-in-java-code

Comment: thx man, I will assign it to him and after it I will let him play with Greenfoot :)